# how to fix image input value "null" in laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel, dropzone.js

in my laravel application I am using dropzone programmatically to upload images. this is my Controller to store images in VehicleController

```
$photos = $request->file('file');
dd($photos);
        if (!is_array($photos)) {
            $photos = [$photos];
        }

        if (!is_dir($this->photos_path)) {
            mkdir($this->photos_path, 0777);
        }

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($photos); $i++) {
            $photo = $photos[$i];
            $name = sha1(date('YmdHis') . str_random(30));
            $save_name = $name . '.' . $photo->getClientOriginalExtension();//this is line 75
            $resize_name = $name . str_random(2) . '.' . $photo->getClientOriginalExtension();

            Image::make($photo)
                ->resize(250, null, function ($constraints) {
                    $constraints->aspectRatio();
                })
                ->save($this->photos_path . '/' . $resize_name);

            $photo->move($this->photos_path, $save_name);

            $upload = new Upload();
            $upload->filename = $save_name;
            $upload->resized_name = $resize_name;
            $upload->original_name = basename($photo->getClientOriginalName());
            $upload->save();
        }
        return Response::json([
            'message' => 'Image saved Successfully'
        ], 200);
```

and programatically jquery is

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

// Dropzone class:
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#my-dropzone", { url: '/form'});
```

routes

```
Route::post('form','VehicleController@store');
```

My blade file is

```
<div class="dropzone" id="my-dropzone"> 
    <div class="dz-message">

              <div class="col-xs-8">
                 <div class="message">
                    <p>Drop files here or Click to Upload</p>
                 </div>
              </div>
    </div>
    <div class="fallback">
        <input type="file" name="file" multiple>

    </div>
</div>
```

but when my form submit button clicked following errors occurred,

```
1/1) FatalErrorException

Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null
in VehicleController.php line 75
```

when I use dd(photos); on

```
$photos = $request->file('file');
```

result comming in 'null' massage then, how can fix this problem?

Comment: Please check below answer.. hope it will work for you..

Comment: where should I put this in my blade file?

Answer (score 4):

```
Please try using below AJAX Code.

<form method="post" action="{{url('form')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Remove the Action(action="{{url('form')}}") from your form Tag.

var datastring = $('#fromid').serialize();  

$.ajax({  

    url: "controller url",  
                    type: 'post',  
                    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",  
                    data: datastring,  
                    success: function(data){  
                        if(data == '100'){  
                            if($('#file').val() != ''){  
                            var form = $('#fromid')[0];   
                            var formData = new FormData(form);  
                            var imageurl='controller image upload url';

                                $.ajax({  
                                    url:imageurl,  
                                    type:"post",  
                                    data:formData,  
                                    processData:false,  
                                    contentType:false,  
                                    cache:false,  
                                    async:false,  
                                    success: function(data){  
                                        setTimeout(function(){  
                                            window.location.href="redirect url";  
                                        },4000);   
                                    }  
                                });  

                            }else{  
                                setTimeout(function(){  
                                    window.location.href="redirct url";  
                                },4000);  
                            }  

                        }else{  
                            alert(data);  
                        }   
                    }  
               });  


-------- Controller code.  
Print_r($_FILES); //You got the result.
```

Comment: where should I put this

Comment: its ajax so you can put it  end of the page and in script tag under the function you have call on submit of form and make sure its ajax so input type should be button.

Answer (score 0):

Please add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in form. Like this:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: **already I have this my form like this <form method="post" action="{{url('form')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">**

Answer (score 0):

Need to add `enctype` attribute as:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">input here</form>
```

Comment: **already I have this my form like this <form method="post" action="{{url('form')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">**